# Generate javascript getters and setters on a generic object

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add a method that would add a getter and setter to every child object of my object.MyObject is a typical poco type object that is flat and contains string and numbers.

Here is what i have tried but i am getting an error.

```
 var MyObject = { Name: "test", age: 54, workplace: "Zoo"}

 for (var key in MyObject) {         

            Object.defineProperty(MyObject [key], key, {
                get: function () {
                    alert("get");
                    return this[key];
                },
                set: function (val) {
                    alert("set")
                    this[key] = val;
                }
            });

        }


MyObject.Name = "lala";
```

and here is my jsfiddle.
https://jsfiddle.net/omp7rzqb/4/

Fixed a typo on my part.It is still not working anyways.

Comment: Why are you doing `this.coreModel`?

Comment: `this` is `window` here, and `window` object has no property like `coreModel`.

Comment: fixed that typo.Still not working.

Comment: You've got another typo from copying and pasting code that you're not familiar with - should be `Object.defineProperty(MyObject, key, {`

Comment: Oh no its not a type.I want to loop thru each object properties and add them a getter and setter.

Comment: You quite misunderstood the idea of custom getters/setters. There you must not use `this` reference since that will produce infinite loop.

Comment: @TotalWar - yes it is a typo. Your current code says something like, on the object **`MyObject.name`**, define a property `name` with custom setters and getters. What you want it to say is that on the object `MyObject`, define a property `name` with custom setters and getters.

Comment: Is this just an exercise or do you have some requirement to do this?

Comment: yes, i want to implement change tracking.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to pass an object to the first parameter of the [**Object.defineProperty()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) function.

But, You cannot access a property in the **getters** and **setters** by the same name as a property you're defining using `Object.defineProperty()`, and this will cause a recursion. So it will recursively invoke the getter and/or setter.

So you can define another property for field values in order to access to them when you use `Object.defineProperty()`.

So we will define the getters/setters in the prototype.

```
  var MyObject = {
    Name: "test",
    age: 54,
    workplace: "Zoo"
  };

  //Define a propperty for field value
  Object.defineProperty(MyObject, '__', {
    value: {}
  });

  //Iterate about all keys of MyObject
  Object.keys(MyObject).forEach(function(prop){
    //Save value current object
    var value = MyObject[prop];
    //For each keys, define a property for prop
    Object.defineProperty(MyObject, prop, {
      get: function(){ return this.__[prop] },
      set: function(data){ this.__[prop] = data}
    });
    //Set current value with new setters
    MyObject[prop] = value;
  });

  console.log(MyObject.Name);
  //test

  MyObject.Name = 'Toto';

  console.log(MyObject.Name);
  //Toto
```